# Is it bad to have Unit Tests return async void?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asynchronous

I know it is bad practice to have a method return async void since it makes it hard to test, but is there any reason that a unit test needs to return async Task rather than async void?

Basically is this ok:

```
[Test()]
public async void MyTest()
{
    //Some code to run test
    //Assert Something
}
```

Or should I be doing this:

```
[Test()]
public async Task MyTest()
{
    //Some code to run test
    //Assert Something
}
```

Comment: Do you want to know if your test ends, when your test ends, and whether or not your test completed successfully?

Comment: Most unit test runners support `async void` methods (by using a custom synchronization context). Still, it's cleaner/safer to use `async Task` for your tests

Comment: @KevinGosse There are still lots of things that you can do in your method that would prevent the testing framework from working properly, even with a custom sync context.  (For example, some code with `ConfigureAwait(false);` is all it takes to break things.)

Comment: @Servy Actually, the `OperationCompleted` event of the synchronization context will be triggered only at the end of the `async void` method, even if you use `.ConfigureAwait(false)` in the middle. I'm sure there's some edge cases, but it's harder to break than it looks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To quote [Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx) By Stephen Cleary

> Void-returning async methods have a specific purpose: to make
>   asynchronous event handlers possible. It is possible to have an event
>   handler that returns some actual type, but that doesn't work well with
>   the language; invoking an event handler that returns a type is very
>   awkward, and the notion of an event handler actually returning
>   something doesn't make much sense. Event handlers naturally return
>   void, so async methods return void so that you can have an
>   asynchronous event handler. However, some semantics of an async void
>   method are subtly different than the semantics of an async Task or
>   async Task method.
>
> Async void methods have different error-handling semantics. When an
>   exception is thrown out of an async Task or async Task method, that
>   exception is captured and placed on the Task object. With async void
>   methods, there is no Task object, so any exceptions thrown out of an
>   async void method will be raised directly on the
>   SynchronizationContext that was active when the async void method
>   started.

Those last few sentences sum it up nicely.

Long story short, use `async Task` for asynchronous test methods.

```
[Test()]
public async Task MyTest()
{
    //Some code to run test
    //Assert Something
}
```

You should really spend some time reading the linked article. It's author has a lot more resources in that subject matter and it will help you understand the semantics behind async/await

Comment: The void tests would still pick up the exception if they happen during an Assert.Thrown correct? The problem would only be if the other lines of code throw an error? I'll switch to the Task return tests though to be safe.

Comment: @NoahLarky: No, they would not. The `Task` is what enables calling code to detect completion and exceptions. `async void` on MSTest is not supported; they simply won't be run.